# is there any convenient way to get a index of sub section in a page?

Tags: python, url, web-scraping

it is convenient to use "index-x" to quick locate a sub section in a page.

for instance

```
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-2
```

gives 3rd sub-section in this [page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

when i want to share the location of a sub-section to others, how to get the index in a convenient way?

for instance, how to get the index of `{m,n}` sub-section without counting from index-0?

[image]

Comment: What does "`{m,n}` sub-section" mean? Also, you can look for anchor tags in the source of the page to find the possible values that can be used after the hash sign.

Comment: @ForceBru did you do this yourself or you just talk about generally without hands on?

Comment: Specifically that section? [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-7) gets you pretty close, are you actually looking for a programatic solution or a link to the docs?

Comment: Also, all you need to do is inspect the page source and find the closest index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use `:has` and `:contains` to target a specific text string and return the index (note that using `select_one` will return first match. Use a list comprehension and `select` if want to return all matches

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
index = soup.select_one('dl:has(.pre:contains("{m,n}"))')['id']
print(index)
```

---

Any version: if you want a dictionary that maps special characters to indices. Thanks to @zoe for spotting the error in my dictionary comprehension.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
mappings = dict([(item['id'], [i.text for i in item.select('dt .pre')]) for item in soup.select('[id^="index-"]')])
indices = {i: k for (k, v) in mappings.items() for i in v}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `index-7`.

You can download the HTML of the page and get all the possible values of `index-something` with the following code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode())

result = [t['id'] for t in soup.find_all(id=re.compile('index-\d+'))]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['index-0', 'index-1', 'index-2', 'index-3', 'index-4', 'index-5', 'index-6', 'index-7', 'index-8', 'index-9', 'index-10', 'index-11', 'index-12', 'index-13', 'index-14', 'index-15', 'index-16', 'index-17', 'index-18', 'index-19', 'index-20', 'index-21', 'index-22', 'index-23', 'index-24', 'index-25', 'index-26', 'index-27', 'index-28', 'index-29', 'index-30', 'index-31', 'index-32', 'index-33', 'index-34', 'index-35', 'index-36', 'index-37', 'index-38']
```

The `t` objects in the list comprehension contain the HTML of the tags whose `id` matches the regex.